# Criteria for Preservation of a Module Structure under Extension of Scalars.

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, tensor-products

Let $A\to B$ be a morphism of (commutative) algebras and $M$ a $B$-module. The $A$-bilinear map $B\times M\to M$ given by $(b,m)\mapsto bm$ induces a surjective homomorphism $B\otimes_{A}M\to M$.

Give sufficient and necessary (or at least sufficient) conditions for this mapping to be an isomorphism of $B$-modules.

Comment: For the context of my problem you can actually assume that $A$ is a finitely generated UFD over a field of characteristic $p>0$ (you can even more assume that $A$ is a polynomial ring over $K$), that $B$ is a domain, and that $B$ is faithfully flat as an $A$-module.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Frankild, Sather-Wagstaff, and Wiegand](http://www.math.unl.edu/~rwiegand1/ExtVanish/paper.pdf): As long as ${}_BM$ is finitely generated, $A \longrightarrow B$ is flat local, $\mathfrak{m}_A B = \mathfrak{m}_B$, and the extension of residue fields is an isomorphism, this happens if and only if $\mathrm{Ext}_A^i(B,M)$ is $A$-finitely generated for all $i \geq 1$.

Comment: In fact they need the stronger hypothesis that $A \to B$ is unramified, i.e. that $\mathfrak m_B = \mathfrak m_A B$. They also
restrict to the situation where $M$ is finitely generated as an $A$-mdoule.

Comment: Quite right, I was overhasty.

Comment: @Graham: Nice reference, I'll take a look.
In the context of my problem $B$ is not Noetherian (nor local). 
$A$ is Noetherian nonetheless, and the expansion of every maximal ideal of $A$ is maximal in $B$ (I'm just gonna think about it).

Comment: @Graham: Thanks a lot. 
The reference was very useful. I could solve my problem (and, even more, the solution gave something interesting).

Comment: Outstanding. Glad to hear it.

Comment: Actually, I was (relatively) wrong: see
http://mathoverflow.net/questions/63559/on-the-separability-of-certain-extensions-of-fields